# Особенности архитектуры StringDictionary

Tags: .net, словари

Предыстория:

Все мы прекрасно знакомы со стандартным типом [Dictionary<TKey, TValue>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx), а также его свойством, что при попытке доступа к элементу по несуществующему ключу будет создано исключение [KeyNotFoundException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.collections.generic.keynotfoundexception(v=vs.110).aspx).
Это привычно для всех и подобное поведение ожидаемо для словаря значений

Недавно же я разбирал один код, который выдавал [NullReferenceException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.nullreferenceexception(v=vs.110).aspx) там, где его по логике вещей быть не могло.

Отдебажив его, я обнаружил следующую вещь:
Человек использовал в своем коде [StringDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.collections.specialized.stringdictionary(v=vs.110).aspx) (к слову, весьма радует, ибо я знаю внушающее количество .NET программистов, которые ни разу не заглядывали в [System.Collections.Specialized](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.collections.specialized(v=vs.110).aspx)) и забыл поставить проверку на существование строки по указанному ключу, тем самым словарь молча возвращал `null` и чуть позже код падал, так как строки со значением `null` должны были отсутствовать внутри словаря и проверка на это не подразумевалась

В случае со стандартным `Dictionary` и созданием указанного выше исключения эту ошибку отловить было бы куда проще, однако у `StringDictionary` немного иная *"идеология"*, так что по несуществующему ключу он возвращает `null` (который, к слову, без вызова метода `ContainsKey` неотличим от существующей по указанному ключу строки с `null`-значением)

---

Собственно, сам вопрос:

Почему при проектировании `StringDictionary` отошли от архитектуры привычного всем словаря и вместо логичного выброса соответствующего исключения сделали просто возвращение `null`?

Мне кажется, что подобное решение должно быть подкреплено какими-то серьезными фактами. Из моих догадок: так как `StringDictionary` создан для **быстрого** (`O(1)`) поиска строк в словаре, то есть скорость в данном случае критична, то выбросом исключений решили пренебречь, так как это не самая быстрая операция)
Однако это лишь моя догадка, хотелось бы услышать Ваше мнение/увидеть ссылки по данному вопросу)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Все гораздо проще - Specialized - это рудимент до-генериковского .net 1.1.

Генерик-реализация Dictionary не может возвращать null для несществующих значений - она должна работать и с reference types, и с value types, причем работать одинаково. Вернуть же null для value type несоколько затруднительно.

На момент появления генериков классы из Specialized активно использовались, и их поведение сохранили ради совместимости. В современном проекте единственая причина для работы с Specialized - это необходимость интеграции с legacy кодом.

Они не реализуют новых генерик интерфейсов, они ведут себя странно и непредсказуемо (например, `StringDictionary` приводит ключи к lowercase), и они могут быть медленее новых генериков даже на базовых операциях, например:

```
[Benchmark]
public StringDictionary StringDictionary()
{
    StringDictionary stringDictionary = new StringDictionary();

    foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, 1000000))
    {
        stringDictionary[i.ToString()] = i.ToString();
    }
    return stringDictionary;
}

[Benchmark]
public Dictionary<string, string> NewDictionary()
{
    var stringDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, 1000000))
    {
        stringDictionary[i.ToString()] = i.ToString();
    }
    return stringDictionary;
}
```

---

```
           Method |     Mean |    Error |   StdDev |
----------------- |---------:|---------:|---------:|
 StringDictionary | 694.0 ms | 5.631 ms | 5.268 ms |
    NewDictionary | 280.2 ms | 5.369 ms | 5.022 ms |
```

Comment: Простите, пожалуйста, что так долго не отмечал ответ! Эх. Я жил во лжи. Я всегда считал, что `StringDictionary` будет работать быстрее `Dictionary<string, string>` (кстати, было бы не плохо добавить в ответ тест не только добавления, но и чтения добавленных данных))